# How to set keys for ghostscript filters in the command-line interface?

Tags: pdf, ghostscript

How do I set keys of Ghostscript filters (as documented [here](http://www.ghostscript.com/doc/9.04/Language.htm#Filters)) in the command-line interface?

More precisely, I would like to set the `Predictor` option of the `PNGPredictorEncode` filter in the following script:

```
gs \
 -sDEVICE=pdfwrite \
 -dGrayImageFilter=/PNGPredictorEncode \
 -sOutputFile=out.pdf \
 in.pdf
```

I have tried to guess the syntax for this and found some ways which do not raise a syntax error (e.g., adding `-dPredictor=10` as an option). However, none of these ways seemed to have any effect (the respective `out.pdf`s were identical to the pixel).

Comment: You probably have to pass some PostScript to GhostScript, as the [commandline parameters affect only the systemdict](http://www.ghostscript.com/doc/9.07/Use.htm#Options).